# Cannot fork laravel/framework

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php

I forked laravel/framework and I try to install it with composer using vcs repository.

```
{
  "repositories":[{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/ldynia/framework.git"
  }],
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "master", 
  },
  ...
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
}
```

Unfortunately, it results with bellow errors. How can I fix this?

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework dev-master
- ldynia/core dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.1.x-dev].
- ldynia/core dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-master, 5.1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-master, 5.1.x-dev].
- Installation request for laravel/framework master -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[dev-master].
- Installation request for ldynia/core dev-master -> satisfiable by ldynia/core[dev-master].
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias):

```
{
  "repositories":[{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/ldynia/framework"
  }],
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "dev-master as 5.1.99", 
  },
  ...
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
}
```

Comment: In which composer file did you add the vcs? The root or in a package?

Comment: I believe that this gist will answer your question https://gist.github.com/ldynia/3c213746cfe0ead7c150

Comment: try using `dev-master as 5.1.99` if you are using the master branche